# string_builder decorator in python 2.7 - how to do it and should I?

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, stringbuilder

So, there is no explicit C#- or Java-style StringBuilder class provided with Python.
Note, I am a bit new to Python, so I am not sure if my idea is a good one.

Suppose I want to have a decorator (if possible) that would join the iterables together. This particular example can be implemented differently, but I can think of other use cases. So ...

```
@string_builder
def build_insert_statement(table_name, col_names, values, where_clause):
    yield 'insert into '
    yield table_name
    yield ' ( '
    yield ', '.join(col_names)
    yield ' ) values ( '
    yield ', '.join(values)
    yield ' ) where '
    yield where_clause
    yield ';'
```

Again, I know that there are alternative ways to do this. However, can this be done? Can a decorator always respect the original function's signature or only sometimes or not at all? If this is possible, then is it a heresy? Why?

Comment: It's not *called* `StringBuilder`, but you can use the `cStringIO.StringIO` class, or on Python 3 the `io.StringIO` class.  Also, naive string building on Python is actually quite fast.

Comment: @DietrichEpp `StringIO` is rather inconvenient for this purpose, because it's intended as a mock file, not as a "string builder". And last time I checked it was surprisingly slow (several times slower than a hand-written object wrapping a list of strings and `str.join`) when repeatedly getting the value.

Comment: @delnan: Can you describe how a "mock file" and "string builder" would be different?  Are you sure you're talking about `cStringIO`?  Also, since the OP doesn't get the value more than once, performance in this case is irrelevant.

Comment: I can't say whether this is good practice, but its clever, and I can see it being convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following definition for `string_builder` should work:

```
from functools import wraps

def string_builder(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return ''.join(func(*args, **kwargs))
    return wrapped
```

Using the function defined in your question with `string_builder` as a decorator:

```
>>> build_insert_statement('foo', ['bar'], ['1'], 'baz')
'insert into foo ( bar ) values ( 1 ) where baz;'
```

Note that using [`functools.wraps`][1] is not necessary, but it is good practice because without it the name of the function (`build_insert_statement.__name__`) after decoration would be "wrapped" instead of "build_insert_statement".

**So it is possible, is it a good idea?**

Not for your example, but you said you have other use cases.  A decorator like this is not heresy, but you shouldn't overuse decorators because it can obscure the implementation.

If you are just worried about line length, consider one of the following alternatives:

- Using `''.join()` on a list:

  ```
  def build_insert_statement(table_name, col_names, values, where_clause):
      return ''.join(['insert into ',
                      table_name,
                      ' ( ',
                      ', '.join(col_names),
                      ' ) values ( ',
                      ', '.join(values),
                      ' ) where ',
                      where_clause,
                      ';'])
  ```
- Combining the strings with `+`:

  ```
  def build_insert_statement(table_name, col_names, values, where_clause):
      return ('insert into ' +
              table_name +
              ' ( ' +
              ', '.join(col_names) +
              ' ) values ( ' +
              ', '.join(values) +
              ' ) where ' +
              where_clause +
              ';')
  ```

Comment: To be honest, I find that I start doing weird things such as shortening of the variable names and introducing extra variables and formatting strings in a different way all because I have to fit in the 80 characters per line limit :( Again, this probably stems from inexperience, but having to worry about the length of the line is currently reducing my quality of life.

Comment: A character limit is always a soft limit. If you can't follow it without hurting the code and its readability, don't do it. And btw, you can wrap lines in Python using the backslash character. That being said, I don't really get how this relates to the question. Is the reason you want that decorator that you want to have it in multiple lines? You could always build a list and join that in the end.